# std::unordered_map and key built of multiple elements

Tags: c++, c++11

I'd like to store in map objects wrapping network connections, where key should be IP address + port number.

My question is how should I handle such key with two elements?

I can define `std::unordered_map<std::pair<std::string, uint16_t>, Connection>`, but I'm not sure how should I implement hash object for it. Only naive implementation comes to my mind:

```
std::size_t operator() (const pair<std::string, uint16_t>& key) const
{
    std::hash<std::string> ip_hash;
    std::hash<uint16_t>    port_hash;

    return ip_hash (key.first) + port_hash (port.second);
}
```

I assume that simple addition of two hash values is rather bad idea. Are there any general rules that i should obey to when implementing hash functions?

(I know, that i can build a string from IP address and port number, but I'm just curious).

Comment: It would be easier to offer suggestions if you explained what you have in mind for `ip_hash` and `port_hash`. Especially the latter -- a port number can serve excellently as its own hash (i.e. hash == identity). If you don't expect many connections from the same IP address you can even take the port out of the equation entirely.

Comment: @Jon Well, I will have multiple connections from the same IP, because this software is going to be used in LAN with couple NATs.

Comment: The solution looks ok, but I would combine the values using xor instead of addition since addition will mess up the distribution.

Answer (score 1):

If using boost is an option, [`boost::hash_combine`](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/hash/reference.html#boost.hash_combine) makes this really easy (otherwise the implementation is available on the linked page).

```
std::size_t operator()(const pair<std::string, uint16_t>& key) const
{
    std::size_t seed = 0;
    boost::hash_combine(seed, key.first);
    boost::hash_combine(seed, key.second);
    return seed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A trivial solution will be to append the uint16_t port number to the string, representing the IP address. Then you can use `std:unordered_map<string, Connection>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your hashing is mostly fine for non security practices. You can make it more robust this way:

```
struct ip_port_hash
{
    size_t operator() (const std::pair< std::string, uint16_t >& key) const
    {
        std::hash<const char*> ip_hash;
        std::hash<size_t>      size_t_hash;

        return size_t_hash( ip_hash (key.first.c_str()) + key.second);
    }
};
```